# Closest value find from array object element using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

**How to find user_value closest value from this array?
Here is user_value variable according to this i need find out closest value from array.**

```
var user_value = 5500;
var array = [ 

    {_id: 5809e269d60f577ae35f6add,
      coins: 1000,
      is_active: 1,
      iconId: 4 },
    {_id: 5809e269d60f577ae35f6ade,
      coins: 2000,
      is_active: 1,
      iconId: 5 },
    {_id: 5809e269d60f577ae35f6adf,
      coins: 5000,
      is_active: 1,
      iconId: 6 },
    {_id: 5809e269d60f577ae35f6ae0,
      coins: 7000,
      is_active: 1,
      iconId: 7 },
    {_id: 5809e269d60f577ae35f6ae1,
      coins: 10000,
      is_active: 1,
      iconId: 8 },
    {_id: 5809e269d60f577ae35f6ae2,
      coins: 15000,
      is_active: 1,
      iconId: 9 } ];
```

Comment: How do you define the closest?

Comment: what us closest here? where you defined it?

Comment: coins filed compare for closest

Comment: user_value  and array coins field compare for closest

Comment: i need closest index from array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an iterative approach by using the absolute difference for checking.

```js
var value = 5500,
    array = [{ _id: '5809e269d60f577ae35f6add', coins: 1000, is_active: 1, iconId: 4 }, { _id: '5809e269d60f577ae35f6ade', coins: 2000, is_active: 1, iconId: 5 }, { _id: '5809e269d60f577ae35f6adf', coins: 5000, is_active: 1, iconId: 6 }, { _id: '5809e269d60f577ae35f6ae0', coins: 7000, is_active: 1, iconId: 7 }, { _id: '5809e269d60f577ae35f6ae1', coins: 10000, is_active: 1, iconId: 8 }, { _id: '5809e269d60f577ae35f6ae2', coins: 15000, is_active: 1, iconId: 9 }],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        return i && Math.abs(aa[r].coins - value) < Math.abs(a.coins - value) ? r : i;
    }, -1);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you define the *closest* as `Math.abs(array[i].coins - value);`, you just need to iterate the array like below:

```js
var user_value = 5500;
var array = [
  {
    coins: 1000,
    is_active: 1,
    iconId: 4
  },
  {
    coins: 2000,
    is_active: 1,
    iconId: 5
  },
  {
    coins: 5000,
    is_active: 1,
    iconId: 6
  },
  {
    coins: 7000,
    is_active: 1,
    iconId: 7
  },
  {
    coins: 10000,
    is_active: 1,
    iconId: 8
  },
  {
    coins: 15000,
    is_active: 1,
    iconId: 9
  }
];

function findClosest (value) {
  // By default that will be a big number
  var closestValue = Infinity;
  // We will store the index of the element
  var closestIndex = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    var diff = Math.abs(array[i].coins - value);
    if (diff < closestValue) {
      closestValue = diff;
      closestIndex = i;
    }
  }
  return closestIndex;
}

console.log("The closest index: " + findClosest(user_value));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var user_value = 5500;
var array = [ 

    { _id: '5809e269d60f577ae35f6add',
      coins: 1000,
      is_active: 1,
      iconId: 4 },
    { _id: '5809e269d60f577ae35f6ade',
      coins: 2000,
      is_active: 1,
      iconId: 5 },
    { _id: '5809e269d60f577ae35f6adf',
      coins: 5000,
      is_active: 1,
      iconId: 6 },
    { _id: '5809e269d60f577ae35f6ae0',
      coins: 7000,
      is_active: 1,
      iconId: 7 },
    { _id: '5809e269d60f577ae35f6ae1',
      coins: 10000,
      is_active: 1,
      iconId: 8 },
    { _id: '5809e269d60f577ae35f6ae2',
      coins: 15000,
      is_active: 1,
      iconId: 9 } ];
function getClosest(array, target) {
    var tuples = _.map(array, function(json) {
        return [json, Math.abs(json.coins - target)];
    });
    //console.log(tuples);
    return _.reduce(tuples, function(memo, val) {
        return (memo[1] < val[1]) ? memo : val;
    }, [-1, 999])[0];
}

console.log(getClosest(array, user_value))
```